# Proper Edge Recombination Crossover for DNA assembly

Tags: python, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I was trying to implement genetic algorithm to assemble DNA fragments into one sequence given only the spectrum. My only operator is Edge Recombination and I was convinced that it's enough to get a pretty good result.

But... i can't beat 80% (% of optimum score) and instances with 500 fragments can take to 2 hours (algorithm stops if there is no improvement in 100 iterations). Am I even implementing it right? I didn't find anywhere that crossover operators should choose elements that are matching better (overlapping of fragments - in most paper it's just random what we pick), but I implemented it that it picks the best matching one, and if there are many - random one. Without picking the best one it doesn't even score 40%.

Should I implement more crossovers? Or it's just not how it works... Or am I missing something? I'm quite desperate at this point, waiting 24hours for 40 instances that simple heuristics (hill climber) can do under 5 seconds...

There's the code (permutation is a shuffled spectrum - list of strings)

```
    def crossover(g1, g2, arr, ind):  # edge recombination operator
    neigh_list = {}  # adjacency list
    length = len(g1.permutation)  # expected length of a child
    for i, base in enumerate(g1.permutation):  # create nodes
        neigh_list[base] = {g1.permutation[i - 1], g1.permutation[(i + 1) % length]}
    for i, base in enumerate(g2.permutation):  # add neighbours to each node
        neigh_list[base].add(g2.permutation[i - 1])
        neigh_list[base].add(g2.permutation[(i + 1) % length])

    # a starting point of a child is a starting point of one of the parents
    neigh_chosen = [g1.permutation[0], g2.permutation[0]][random.randint(0, 1)]
    child = [neigh_chosen]

    while len(child) < length:  # run until child has desired length
        min_length = 5  # each list has lower length than 5
        min_neigh_list = []
        for k in neigh_list:  # for every node
            if neigh_chosen in neigh_list[k]:  # remove a chosen fragment from the node
                neigh_list[k].remove(neigh_chosen)
        for k in neigh_list[neigh_chosen]:  # if a node is a neighbour of previously chosen
            if len(neigh_list[k]) < min_length:  # remember nodes with the fewest neighbours
                min_length = len(neigh_list[k])
                min_neigh_list = [k]
            elif len(neigh_list[k]) == min_length:
                min_neigh_list.append(k)
        del neigh_list[neigh_chosen]  # delete list of the chosen node
        if len(min_neigh_list) > 0:  # if the chosen node has any neighbours
            # get the best match out of neighbours as next
            max_overlap = overlap(neigh_chosen, max(min_neigh_list, key=lambda x: overlap(neigh_chosen, x)))
            possibilities = list(filter(lambda x: overlap(neigh_chosen, x) == max_overlap, min_neigh_list))
            neigh_chosen = possibilities[random.randint(0, len(possibilities) - 1)]
        else:
            # get the best match out of every node as next
            max_overlap = overlap(neigh_chosen, max(neigh_list, key=lambda x: overlap(neigh_chosen, x)))
            possibilities = list(filter(lambda x: overlap(neigh_chosen, x) == max_overlap, neigh_list))
            neigh_chosen = possibilities[random.randint(0, len(possibilities) - 1)]
        child.append(neigh_chosen)  # add the node to the solution
    arr[ind] = Gene(child)
```

Comment: You will struggle to get an answer here I think (or anywhere) since this is quite specialist. I'm interested in what you're doing (I don't profess to be able to answer) but one thing that would help me here is if you stuck to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to break up that giant block of code. Even then, though, I think it would take some real effort to go through heuristics.

Comment: You might get good answers on the new Bioinformatics Stack Exchange site: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109245/bioinformatics

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to solve this one doing a pretty easy trick. The problem was in understanding what this operator actually does and where to use it. To make it help doing the DNA assembly problem just replace

```
    for k in neigh_list[neigh_chosen]:  # if a node is a neighbour of previously chosen
        if len(neigh_list[k]) < min_length:  # remember nodes with the fewest neighbours
            min_length = len(neigh_list[k])
            min_neigh_list = [k]
        elif len(neigh_list[k]) == min_length:
            min_neigh_list.append(k)
    del neigh_list[neigh_chosen]
```

with

```
    min_neigh_list = neigh_list[neight_chosen]
    del neigh_list[neigh_chosen]
```

The reason it works is because we are not looking for a fragment with minimum number of neighbours (it might be important in other kind of graph related problem!) but a neighbour with the best match!

It works like a charm after this simple change :)

Comment: just curious, does it still take 2 hours?

Comment: Right now it give 95+% score and takes from 5sec to 240s per problem instance (300 fragments to 700 fragments)